# Shell(bash) script for looping by taking two argument from each lines in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I'd like to write a script to boot some daemons.
I've maintained some scripts which have same contents without `username`s and `path`s.
However, to make the script more generally, I tried to make it more generic and doing by a loop.

These are generalized input and script that I want to run.

Input file: `input.txt`

```
pathA userA
pathB userB
...
pathZ userZ
```

Working script: `echos.sh`

```
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"
```

And, the expected result is:

```
1: pathA
2: userA
1: pathB
2: userB
....
1: pathZ
2: userZ
```

However, I could not write the right script which gives the expected result.

This is a script which I write. (I knew this must fail...): `loop.sh` (I run like `$ loop.sh input.txt`)

```
#listfile=$1
listlines=`cat $1`
for args in $listlines
do
    bash echos.sh $args
done
```

How could I get/fix it?

## Edited

I'm sorry that I forget to remove `echo $args` from `loop.sh`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this answers your question, but I'm not sure. It was a little unclear to me.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
  >&2 echo "Missing input file argument; exiting."
  exit 1
fi

while read -r path user ; do
  echo "1: $path"
  echo "2: $user"
done < "$1"
```

The `input.txt` file contains:

```
pathA userA
pathB userB
pathZ userZ
```

Example output:

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ ./loop.sh
Missing intput file argument; exiting.
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ ./loop.sh input.txt
1: pathA
2: userA
1: pathB
2: userB
1: pathZ
2: userZ
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but I *think* you are looking for:

```
while read path user; do 
    bash echos.sh $path $user
done < input.txt
```